# How to change new line text breaking rule in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, word-break

I`m trying to make an icon to be close to the text. The text can have different length. 
The problem is when there are to much text for 1 line, it breaks text into the new line, but the text block takes the whole space, even if the text breaks earlier. The closest solution is word-break: break-all. But it's not suitable.

It there any other way to change text breaking rule? Or to make something with .text block to end directly where the text breaks?

Here the example:
[image]

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  width: 125px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">text text text text text</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="text">text text</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: To clarify, you want the icon to be after the last word, inline with the text, almost as if it were another text character?

Comment: _“Or to make something with .text block to end directly where the text ends?”_ - no, that is close to impossible using current CSS.

Comment: @sean I add image to shouw how it should be

Answer (score 2):

you can add the `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap` properties

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  width: 125px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
}

.noBreak{
  width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text noBreak">text text text text text</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="text">text text</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Edit 1.0:

To keep multiple line text

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  width: 125px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;   
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text noBreak">text text text text text
  <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="text">text text</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Edit 2.0:

For an image it would look like:

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  width: 125px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.icon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png"); 
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text noBreak">text text text text text
  <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="text noBreak">text text
  <div class="icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I need to keep multiline text

Comment: thanks, but it's cut the text. I'm trying to make a little bit different. It`s not a usual behavior. I added a picture. I'm thinking that it is impossible (

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  width: 125px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text {
flex: 0 0 100px;
}

.icon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">text text text text text</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="text">text text</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Sonia. I'm trying to make a little bit different. It`s not a usual behavior. I added a picture. But now I'm thinking that it is impossible (

Comment: @Volodymyr, Can you please share the code